# pass over errors with for loops and fill in row with None

Tags: pandas, dataframe, try-catch, geopy, nominatim

i am using a for loop to iterate over rows in a data frame and apply a function to values in two of the columns to get coordinates from a city name using geopy. Some of the values throw errors and i want to use a try / except (or catch?) inside the for loop so that in the case that applying geopy to one of the values throws an error, python just fills in that row with 'None' and then i can go back and delete those rows with 'None'. is there a way to do that? here is the code i am working with:

```html
list_lat = []   # create empty list for lat
list_long = [] # create empty list for long

for index, row in df.iterrows(): # iterate over rows in dataframe
    try:
        City = row['City Name']
        State = row['State Name']       
        query = str(City)+','+str(State)

        location = geolocator.geocode(query)
        lat = location.latitude
        long = location.longitude
        #print(lat, long) #testing purposes

        list_lat.append(lat)
        list_long.append(long)
    
    
    except Exception as e:
        
#         lat = 'None'
#         long = 'None'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like lat and long to be added as a column, you can try something like this.

```
def fn(row):
    city = row['City Name']
    State = row['State Name']       
    query = str(City)+','+str(State)
    try:
        location = geolocator.geocode(query)
        lat = location.latitude
        long = location.longitude
        return lat,long
    except:
        return np.NaN,np.NaN

df[['lat','long']] = df.apply(lambda x: fn(x),axis=1,result_type='expand')
```

This will result in 2 extra columns with corresponding lat and long result from function.

And to delete NaN values you can use

```
df.dropna()
```

But do keep in mind, iterating each row individually can be slow for huge data set

Comment: thank you! i have noticed that it is extremely slow--i had to cut it down from 31000 rows to a sample of 4000. is there a faster way?

Comment: Sorry, since you need to use try/except and iterate over each row, I am not familiar with other ways that can achieve this without the use of custom functions. I will do my research on this and try to get back to you in-case I stumble upon anything. Meanwhile, we can wait for other answers.